# Why did I get a different name?

Tags: bug, display-names

I got some curious here.

On Stack Exchange, my preview name is a regular text (Ahmad Azwar Anas).
But in another portal, in example, the Ubuntu portal, I got some alphanumeric combination, such as userXXXX.

What is going on? Can it become a single preview?

A link that explains it clearly will be admirable.
Hehehe. I can not find it through Google.
{Oh... my bad.}

Comment: We have a bug... *somewhere*. I think there are a few related issues going on, and we've been investigating. I should have more news next week. In the meantime, feel free to edit your profile on that site to set the name, etc. you want. Sorry about that.

Comment: ok brother.. I'll be waiting that next bug-fix. Hope done soon.

Comment: @AhmadAzwarAnas You can fix your names on the other sites without waiting for the bug to be fixed. The bug only happens when you sign up on a new site.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie thanks brother. I got that. Only profile picture that seem can not be changed together.